# Cannot successfully reload UITableView elements when parsing data from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an app where users can buy and sell tickets. Users are able to create a new ticket and it successfully uploads to firebase however a reference to the ticket ID is stored in the user data which references the ticket id in the ticket data. The structure of the database is below:

DATABASE

- USERS
- TICKETS

TICKETS

- TICKET INFO

USER

- USER INFO AND TICKET ID OF TICKETS THEY ARE SELLING

My problem is that the first time I load the tickets from the selling tickets it's fine. However when the user adds a new ticket that they are selling, the table view loads everything twice.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tickets = []
    DataService.ds.REF_USER_CURRENT.child("selling").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in //HERE WE REFERNCE OUR SINGELTON CLASS AND OBSERVE CHAMGE TO THE POSTS OBJECT
        self.tickets = [] //WE CLEAR THE POSTS ARRAY BEFORE WE START MANIPULATION TO MAKE SURE THAT WE DONT REPEAT CELLS
        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]{
            print("ADAM: \(snapshot)")//CHECKING THAT THE OBJECTS EXIST AS AN ARRAY OF DATA SNAPSHOTS
            for snap in snapshot {
                DataService.ds.REF_TICKETS.child(snap.key).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    if let ticketDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{

                        let ticket = Ticket(ticketID: snap.key, ticketData: ticketDict)

                        self.self.tickets.append(ticket)
                    }

                    self.sell_ticketsTableView.reloadData()
                })
            }

        }
        //self.sell_ticketsTableView.reloadData()
        self.tickets = []//RELAOD THE DATA
    })
}
```

I'm not quite sure where I have gone wrong.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are doing. What is this code"                        self.self.tickets.append(ticket)
" or this "self.tickets = []"?? what you should do is empty your datasource array before parsing data so you won't have multiple occurrences of the same ticket

Comment: @Siyavash the self.tickets = [] is how I'm trying to clear the data source array as the datasource is the tickets array

Comment: Please look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code to this. I have added the part where you clear your array

```
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.removeAll() // This is how you clear your array
        DataService.ds.REF_USER_CURRENT.child("selling").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in //HERE WE REFERNCE OUR SINGELTON CLASS AND OBSERVE CHAMGE TO THE POSTS OBJECT
            self.tickets = [] //WE CLEAR THE POSTS ARRAY BEFORE WE START MANIPULATION TO MAKE SURE THAT WE DONT REPEAT CELLS
            if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]{
                print("ADAM: \(snapshot)")//CHECKING THAT THE OBJECTS EXIST AS AN ARRAY OF DATA SNAPSHOTS
                for snap in snapshot {
                    DataService.ds.REF_TICKETS.child(snap.key).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                        if let ticketDict = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{

                            let ticket = Ticket(ticketID: snap.key, ticketData: ticketDict)

                            self.tickets.append(ticket)
                        }

                        self.sell_ticketsTableView.reloadData()
                    })
                }

            }
            //self.sell_ticketsTableView.reloadData()
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are observing the value of what a user is selling, which means every time they add something to this list, your listener will trigger and give you the new value of `users/$uid/selling` in its entirety.

This is why you are seeing double when the user adds another ticket; the listener is triggered and you append each ticket to the array again. You can get around this by checking if the ticket is already in the array before you append it however, your current implementation can be improved.

Instead of using `observe(.value`, you should use `.childAdded`. The listener will trigger every time a new child is added and only give you that specific child snapshot.

The listener will initially trigger for each child at that reference and you can append them to the array individually. However, once all the children have been loaded, the next child to be added will trigger this listener, which you can append to the array.

Comment: so when I take a snapshot say, the second time, it will only return the newly added child?

Comment: Using `.childAdded` will only return one child at a time, rather than all of them. This is better since you don't need every other ticket that you already have in your table if the user decides to add another one. It will also trigger after the initial load of the children, when another is added.